# Have Visual Studio check for file-checksum instead of timestamp to determine which file needs to be rebuilt

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Currently I'm managing a huge C++ pullrequest which I (git) rebase regularly on the origin's master to keep it up-to-date.

However Visual Studio seems to rebuild all sources after a rebase because the timestamp of most files changed but the content of most files stayed the same (CMake is used as build system).

**Is there a way to tell Visual Studio compiler to check whether the file content stayed the same (through checksums) instead of using the last timestamp written to the file to prevent it from rebuilding my huge solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to write a script/small software, and include it in the pre-build actions, that checks the before and after source files and if the content has not changed (via a checksum), then it changes the creation date of the after-source file to match the already compiled obj.

Or, even better, the script could be responsible for the source file copying, and it doesn't even copy a source file if its content is the same as the old source.

I don't think VS Builder has such a native option.

Comment: Nice Idea, I was thinking about such a script already... I like the idea of integrating it as part of the build process which should be rather simple to integrate using CMake. There is also the possibility to use git hooks such as `pre-rebase` or `post-commit` which comes into my mind to automate the rewrite of the timestamps.